# VS Code shows an error in tsconfig.json in fresh installation of Nuxt3

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuxt3

There is an error I can't understand:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to install `@types/node` package.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Or if you use yarn you can do it with a yarn command.

Comment: @Don40 Glad it worked! Please make sure to approve the answer :)